# выделение динамической памяти не работает внутри "try"

Tags: c++, исключения

в программе нужно обработать исключения для  new. ТЗ самой программы:

> Открыть файл, считать из него количество символов.
>
> Выделить память под массив типа char.
>
> Считать коды символов.
>
> Передать символы в функцию которая выведет символ и его код.

сам код:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <new>

using namespace std;

void func(char s) {
    int b = int(s);
    cout << "Symbol:" << s << endl;
    cout << "Code:" << b << "\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n = -1;
    char a;
    ifstream F;
    F.open("fl.txt");

    if (F) {
        while (!F.eof())
        {
            F >> a;
            n++;
        }

        F.clear();
        F.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    }

    try
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++)
        {
            char *mass = new char[n];
        }
    }
    catch (char *mass)
    {
        cerr << "При выделении памяти обнаружено ";
    }
                while (!F.eof())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        F >> mass[i];  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор
                }

    mass[n] = '\0';
    for (int c = 0; c<n; c++) {
        func(mass[c]);  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор
    }

    F.close();
    delete[] mass;  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор и error C2541: delete: нельзя удалять объекты, не являющиеся указателями

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки указаны в комментариях у тех самых "проблемных" строк. 
как я поняла, new не работает правильно в try, пыталась выделять память без обработки исключений- ошибок не было. Однако эта обработка нужна.

Много искала, у остальных такой вариант с try и catch'ем работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, весь мозг уже замылен.

Comment: в блоке for внутри try объявляется имя mass с типом char *. область его видимости только тело цикла.

Comment: убрала for, ничего не изменило, те же самые ошибки

Comment: я имел в виду, что-то такое http://www.cpp.sh/2fws4

Comment: Знаете, вы не методом тыка работайте (убрала for - а он точно НЕ НУЖЕН?), а **думайте**.

Answer (score 1):

Просто вынес mass из области видимости try-catch блока, программа запускается без ошибок. Просто все переменные, что Вы определите в блоке {} по выходу из него будут уничтожены, оттуда и ошибка, Вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной, которой просто уже нет. Логику программы не смотрел, только поправил эту ошибку.

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

void func(char s) {
    int b = int(s);
    cout << "Symbol:" << s << endl;
    cout << "Code:" << b << "\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n = -1;
    char a;
    char *mass = nullptr;      // ВОТ ТУТ ПОПРАВКА
    ifstream F;
    F.open("fl.txt");

    if (F) {
        while (!F.eof())
        {
            F >> a;
            n++;
        }

        F.clear();
        F.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    }

    try
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++)
        {
            mass = new char[n];
        }
    }
    catch (char *mass)
    {
        cerr << "При выделении памяти обнаружено ";
    }
                while (!F.eof())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        F >> mass[i];  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор
                }

    mass[n] = '\0';
    for (int c = 0; c<n; c++) {
        func(mass[c]);  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор
    }

    F.close();
    delete[] mass;  // error C2065: mass: необъявленный идентификатор и error C2541: delete: нельзя удалять объекты, не являющиеся указателями

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: new  генерирут  обьект bad_alloc,  а не указатель  на символю В блоке try исключение может броить только оператор new, так что ваш ответ неверный

Answer (score 1):

В блоке `try` исключение может бросить только оператор new,  а этим исключением является обьект  `std::bad_alloc`.

```
catch (std::bad_alloc b) 
{
    cerr << "При выделении памяти обнаружено  генерация исключения "
          <<  b.what();
}
```

Comment: Исключения следует ловить по ссылке

Comment: @alexolut ,  тогда скажите, почему в данном конкретном случаи неправильно  ловить не по ссыльке?

Comment: лишнее копирование объекта

Comment: @alexolut,  нужно сразу написать причину  замечания,  хотябы для тех, кто интересуется и читает.   Иногда исключение нужно ловить по ссыльке, поскольку может быть выкинут обьект  производного класса.  Это уже серьезная причина,  иа для данного случая,  не ссылька подсказывает, что обьект  другого 
 типа не   нужно   ловить, а  копировать такой маленький обьект  типа  std::bad_alloc, имеющий размер одного машинного слова, представляет столько  проблем сколько копирование  встроенных типов.  Это мое мнение, и буду рад слышать, ваше если  я в чем то  не прав

Comment: Дело не в размере. При передаче по значению будет срезка типа, если реальный тип исключения будет производным типом. Со ссылкой такого не произойдёт, и можно адекватно обработать объект исключения виртуальными функциями.

Answer (score 0):

Для понимания кода надо знать как ведет себя та или иная команда.
Найти информацию о том как работает каждая команда можно в любых справочниках, к примеру http://ru.cppreference.com, но лучше использовать английскую версию.

Небольшие пояснения оставил в комментариях к коду.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <new>

using namespace std;

void func(char s) {
    int b = int(s);
    cout << "Symbol:" << s << endl;
    cout << "Code:" << b << "\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char *mass = nullptr; //необходим один массив символов
    int n = 0;  //количество символов считаем с 0
    char a;
    ifstream F;
    F.open("fl.txt");

    if (F) 
    {
        //while (!F.eof()) // данный цикл отрабатывает не корректно, 
        // т.к. флаг окончания файла устанавливается после некорректного чтения, 
        // в результате получим n = (количество символов в файле + 1)

        while (F >> a) //вернет false если не удалось прочитать
        {
            n++;
        }
        F.clear();
        F.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    }
    try
    {
        //создавать 1000 массивов не нужно
        //for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++)
        //{
        //  char *mass = new char[n];
        //}
        mass = new char[n];
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) // new может выбросить исключение std::bad_alloc
    {
        cerr << "При выделении памяти обнаружено: " << ba.what() << '\n';  
    }

    //while (!F.eof()) //  не надо много раз заполнять массив символов из файла
    //{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // достаточно одного цикла
        F >> mass[i]; 
    //}

    for (int c = 0; c<n; c++) {
        func(mass[c]);  
    }

    F.close();
    delete[] mass;  

    return 0;
}
```